# A component passed into connect() is not rendered

Tags: reactjs, redux

In the code below, if I only return a `topic` object from `mapStateToProps`, the `SingleTopic` component is not re-rendered when the state updates. But if I return `{ topic, state }` from it, the component is re-rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SingleTopic from '../components/SingleTopic';
import { incrementTopicRating, decrementTopicRating } from '../actions/forum';

let mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let topic = state.filter((t) => {
    return +t.id === +ownProps.params.id;
  })[0];

  return { topic };
};

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onUpvote: (id) => { dispatch(incrementTopicRating(id)); },
    onDownvote: (id) => { dispatch(decrementTopicRating(id)); }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SingleTopic);
```

I might be doing something wrong, but as far as I understand, the component passed into `connect` is supposed to be updated automatically when the state updates. Could someone explain me where is my mistake?

Reducer:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TOPIC': return addTopic(state, action);
    case 'INCREMENT_TOPIC_RATING': return incrementTopicRating(state, action);
    case 'DECREMENT_TOPIC_RATING': return decrementTopicRating(state, action);
    default: return state;
  }
};

const addTopic = (state, action) => {
  let { title, body, id, rating } = action;
  let newTopic = { title, body, id, rating };
  return [newTopic, ...state];
};

const incrementTopicRating = (state, action) => {
  return state.map((topic) => {
    if (+topic.id === +action.id) {
      topic.rating += 1;
      return topic;
    }
    return topic;
  });
};

const decrementTopicRating = (state, action) => {
  return state.map((topic) => {
    if (+topic.id === +action.id) {
      topic.rating -= 1;
      return topic;
    }
    return topic;
  });
};
```

**UPD**
The `SingleTopic` component is rendered if I add a second property to the returned object. And this property must be of type array or object, like this:

```
let foo = [];

return { topic, foo };
```

Comment: The problem probably lies with your reducer. Can you display that code please?

Comment: Added the reducer. The thing is the state is changes well and `mapStateToProps` is invoked, but component is not rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your were mutating the state in your reducer's `incrementTopicRating` and `decrementTopicRating` methods.

Here is the updated code for your recuder:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TOPIC': return addTopic(state, action);
    case 'INCREMENT_TOPIC_RATING': return incrementTopicRating(state, action);
    case 'DECREMENT_TOPIC_RATING': return decrementTopicRating(state, action);
    default: return state;
  }
};

const addTopic = (state, action) => {
  let { title, body, id, rating } = action;
  let newTopic = { title, body, id, rating };
  return [newTopic, ...state];
};

const incrementTopicRating = (state, action) => {
  const newState = state.map((topic) => {
    if (+topic.id === +action.id) {
      return Object.assign({}, topic, { rating: topic.rating+1 });
    }
    return topic;
  });

  return newState;
};

const decrementTopicRating = (state, action) => {
  return state.map((topic) => {
    if (+topic.id === +action.id) {
      return Object.assign({}, topic, { rating: topic.rating-1 });
    }
    return topic;
  });
};
```

Here is a JSBIN with the corrected solution: https://jsbin.com/nihabaqumo

In order to avoid this kind of issues in the future, consider using a library that allows you to generate immutable data like the facebook [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) one. Use this kind of library to create a state that cannot be changed once created.

***MORE INFO ADDED***

In answer to the question:
*If the `map` method returns a new `array` and is changing the local `topic` variable then I didn't change the previous state, so where is the problem? As I see it `incrementTopicRating` doesn't change previous state and returns a new one. Could you clarify it please?*

In your reducer's code the `map` method does return a new `array` but with the same `object` references.

When `react-redux` checks for a change to define if the component `SingleTopic` should update (be re-rendered) it does a shallow equal check of the new props versus the previous props. Since both the old and new arrays contain references to the same objects, the shallow equal returns true for all object comparisons in the old and new arrays even for the one for which the rating had been modified. The `SingleTopic` component is then not aware of a change and is never re-rendered.

More information can be found here: http://rackt.org/redux/docs/Troubleshooting.html

Also look at the Connect component source code, more specifically the `shouldComponentUpdate` method which determines if a component should be updated/re-rendered or not: https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/04693ca0cabe021b27b62eb9240b51459ffe8c32/src/components/connect.js

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still have a question: If the `map` method returns a new array and changing the local `topic` variable I didn't change the previous state, so where is the problem? As I see it `incrementTopicRating ` don't change previous state and return a new one. Could you clarify it please?

Comment: To answer your question, I have updated my answer with more information.

Comment: deep-freeze should be ideally used in tests only.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is caused because your reducers mutate the items:

```
 if (+topic.id === +action.id) {
      topic.rating -= 1;
      return topic;
 }
```

Try creating a new item instead:

```
if (+topic.id === +action.id) {
      return { ...topic, rating: topic.rating - 1 }; 
}
```